# How much of Xfce4 is GTK3?

Tags: xfce, gtk3, gtk2

Xfce4 was originally in GTK2. But after a recent upgrade to version 4.12, I find it is halfway GTK2 and halfway GTK3. Which applications are currently ported to GTK3 and which are currently not yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such list - and even if one existed, it would be outdated fairly quickly.

This is the case even if you're only counting "official" xfce apps, ignoring the thousands more GTK2 & GTK3 programs that can be run on a system running xfce.

The important thing to know is that, regardless of whether you use xfce or not, if you run GTK apps you will need a theme compatible with both GTK2 and GTK3 installed.  This will be the case for years to come - don't expect this to change any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can see latest progress [here](https://wiki.xfce.org/releng/4.14/roadmap#status) ([more](https://blog.alteroot.org/articles/2017-05-30/road-to-xfce-4.14-part-2.html)). "Facade" info might even be kinda outdated, but if you check each specific component, I think they are almost always updated asap from developers themselves.